# Dynamic id rendering not working in nextjs 13.4.6

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, next.js

[image][image]

i am learning next-js .. before this project i used the dynamic id rendering .
but now this throws some error
Dynamic Id rendering not working in next js 13.4.6.
i can't find the error .
is it because i dont have pages folder instead of app folder

Comment: try to pass 'userid' instead of 'user.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the `app` folder-based routing (which is new in NextJS 13) instead of the older `page` folder-based routing, so you have to create a dynamic folder name route. In your case it will be `[user]` and inside that you will have to add `page.js` file.

So your directory structure will look like this:

```
/project-name
├─ app/
│  ├─ [user]/
│  │  ├─ error.js
│  │  ├─ layout.js
│  │  ├─ page.js
│  ├─ error.js
│  ├─ layout.js
│  ├─ page.js
```

Your main logic for the page will always reside in the `page.js` file. For more detailed understanding of this you can explore the [NextJS documentation on server components routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing) or look at this [Fireship video](https://youtu.be/__mSgDEOyv8)